# Find column value from one sheet based on the order # on another sheet

Tags: excel, excel-formula, match, vlookup

So, on Sheet1, I have Data based on an Order # and I want the Multiplier that is associated with it. The Multiplier is on Sheet2 with the Order #, but the Order #'s and Multipliers associated always change spots every day so I cannot just copy and paste. I want the Multipler in line with the correct Order # on Sheet1. I figured to use some sort of VLOOKUP function but I am not sure what to do. I attached two pictures to help with the scenario.

[image: Sheet1]

[image: Sheet2]

Comment: Change your column A's cell number format from `General` to `0` to avoid the conversion to scientific notation.

Comment: Have you already tried using `VLOOKUP()` and did you run into an error?

Comment: Yes, but honestly I have very limited experience with it and other sites were a bit confusing. So, I find everyone here more helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Sheet1!D2,

```
=index(sheet2!d:d, match(a2, sheet2!b:b, 0))
'error controlled
=iferror(index(sheet2!d:d, match(a2, sheet2!b:b, 0)), text(,))
```

Comment: Thank you, if there are more Order #'s and Multipliers in Sheet3 (in the same cell columns), how would I index for ALSO Sheet3?

Comment: What does 'also' mean? Addition, multiplication, string concatenation or other?

Comment: Sorry, "also" wasn't being used as a function. I mean that I want to grab Multipliers from Sheet3 as well since some order numbers are on Sheet3 (I did not add a picture but it is in the same range as Sheet2). Can there be a way to get the same formula you wrote, but for both Sheet2 and Sheet3?

Comment: It looks like you are asking a new question that is outside your original scope. If this solution worked for your first question you should accept it, and create a new question for your second problem.

Comment: @user10003190 Yes but what do you want to do with two values? Add them togeter, multiply then against each other, concatenate hem into a string with a delimiter or what?

Comment: @user10003190 Fair enough.